# Unabel to save the HTML input values in SharePoint Custom Form

Tags: sharepoint

i have a SharePoint Custom Edit form which includes Html controls along with sharepoint controls.

I would like to save the Html control values using JSOM to the list as well as save the SharePoint Control Values for the same.

I tried to trigger the custom save button on item updation code through JSOM, but receives save conflict error.

Appreciate your help on this

Comment: We might be able to help if you include some of your HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Save conflict error occurs when you try to update an item without fetching the latest value.  In your case try updating the item after doing a getitem.